# Log4j not compressing correctly

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

Below is the log4j.properties file

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file


    # Redirect log messages to a log file
    log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy  
    log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${catalina.home}/logs/app.log  
    log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${catalina.home}/logs/app-.%d{yyyyMMdd-HH}.log.gz  
    log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
    log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
    log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%
```

The file is getting compressed but not at 10MB. After compression the filesize is 14MB...Something seems weird

Comment: what is the actual size?@Priyanka

Comment: before compression u mean? How do i find that out? After compression it comes to 13.5MB..one file even came to 99.1 MB

Answer (score 0):

There is some change in appender, Can you test it

```
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy  
log4j.appender.file.triggeringPolicy=org.apache.log4j.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy 
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.ActiveFileName=${catalina.home}/logs/app.log  
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.FileNamePattern=${catalina.home}/logs/app-.%d{yyyyMMdd-HH}.log.gz  
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.triggeringPolicy.MaxFileSize=10MB  
log4j.appender.file.rollingPolicy.maxIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%
```

Comment: what is difference between this n what i have posted

Comment: This does not compress. It simply created a file with extension .gz, This cannot be openned in winzip and when i remove the gz extension it opens as regular text file in notepad